# How to generate multiple swagger.json files for a each API in a single spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I was able to get the 'swagger-ui' to display the rest API documentation using Springfox for an example spring boot app. But the actual app has a lot many APIs and hence a single HTML page would be cumbersome to browse through. Is there a way to split the APIs into multiple 'swagger.json' files and then reference each page based on the API the user wants to understand?